# Fast and reliable method of determining the overall trend of the data

Tags: trend, test-for-trend

I have oscillating data that could have a linear trend. However, the data (~1e6 points) is highly oscillating and it is impossible to determine the slope exactly due to statistical fluctuations. The oscillations are of sinusoidal nature, so locally (small scale) there are a lot of superpositions of sine waves of various frequencies:

[image: Hihgly oscillating data]

My task is to determine the slope, or at least claim the confidence limits for it:
$$
m \pm \Delta m
$$
if we assume that the data comes from a simple linear model $y = mx + b$

I need a fast yet reliable method for this task, overshooting with $\Delta m$ is not as important as mistakenly undershooting, as I am claiming the significance of the slope as $m/\Delta m$.

Things I tried:

1. Fitting and extracting fit errors for $m$ (not reliable as I get very large values of $\Delta m$ due to large oscillations, even when the trend is clear to the naked eye)
2. Averaging data into (say like 100points) and repeating 1. Does not work properly as the problem just translates to the small scale variant (100points). There are still oscillations and it is hard to claim the trend.
3. Bayesian analysis (too expensive computationally)

Comment: Apart from tiny wobbles at the top and bottom, that picture is solid blue so there is nothing clear to the naked eye.  But there is nothing to suggest a slope

Comment: In this picture, there is no trend. But how can I assign the confidence limits of the trend?